# Simple clojure : Why output of different expressions are same?

Tags: clojure

```
(map (comp #(- 9  %) *) [2 4 6] [0 0 0])
```

output : `(9 9 9)`

```
(map (comp #(+ 9  %) *) [2 4 6] [0 0 0])
```

output : `(9 9 9)`

Why these give same output? `#(- 9  %)` and `#(+ 9 %)` are different.

Comment: To start with, the output of (- 9 0) and (+ 9 0) is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general

```
(map (comp f g) s t)
```

... can be refactored as

```
(map f (map g s t))
```

In this case,

```
(map (comp #(- 9  %) *) [2 4 6] [0 0 0])
```

... becomes

```
(map #(- 9  %) (map * [2 4 6] [0 0 0]))
```

... which reduces to

```
(map #(- 9  %) '(0 0 0))
```

So changing `-` to `+` makes no difference.

---

The above is essentially an explanation of [cfrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40025134/1562315).

Answer (score 8):

You are mulitplying each number with zero:

```
(map * [2 4 6] [0 0 0])
;; -> (0 0 0)
```

So what remains: `9-0 == 9+0`